# Unable to map collections with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map DTOs to Entities with AutoMapper in a .Net Core application that is using Entity Framework.

Whenever I am trying to map collections, I this exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[TDestination]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[TDestination]'
```

This is happening when I am trying to update an existing entity like this:

```
mapper.Map(source, destination);
```

This happens because there is a collection in an IEnumerable property in the objects.
This property is initialized to a HashSet by Entity Framework in the destination object and to a List by the JSON deserializer in the source object.

I found a few issues on GitHub regarding my issue, however the solution mentioned is not working for me:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2397

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2435

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2436

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2447

The solution mentioned in the issues above is to use `UseDestinationValue` on the destination member when setting up the mapping.

Here is a minimal example that illustrates my issue:

**AMTest.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Automapper" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Automapper.Collection" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**AMTest.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.EquivalencyExpression;
using Xunit;

namespace AMTest
{
    public class SourceItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public IEnumerable<SourceItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class DestinationItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        public IEnumerable<DestinationItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddCollectionMappers();

                cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, DestinationItem>()
                    .EqualityComparison((s, d) => s.Id == d.Id);

                cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Items, o => o.UseDestinationValue());
            });

            var mapper = new Mapper(config);

            var src = new Source
            {
                Items = new List<SourceItem>(),
            };

            var dest = new Destination
            {
                Items = new HashSet<DestinationItem>(),
            };

            mapper.Map(src, dest);
        }
    }
}
```

According to the GitHub issues I found online, this setup should work, but it does not.

Can you help me figure out why?

Comment: Don't use `IEnumerable`, use `IList` or `ICollection`.

Comment: This indeed solved my issue. Why was `IEnumerable` causing issues?

Comment: When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. `IEnumerable` has no `Clear` method, so we just assume `IList`.